# I got a problem installing bundler when trying create my new react native project am using Mac OS high sierra

Tags: react-native, bundler, npx

and this was my terminal output

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Bundler
error 
✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
    at createFromTemplate (/Users/techero/.npm/_npx/1164/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:169:11)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/Users/techero/.npm/_npx/1164/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:222:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/techero/.npm/_npx/1164/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:140:9).
```

please help me fixing this bug ..I have walking around trying different option but no result

I run npx react-native init myapp and also I have run react native doctor and this was the result..please I need help fixing this bug....

```
Techeros-MacBook-Pro:myapp techero$ npx react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm
 ● Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

iOS
 ✖ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
   - Version found: N/A
   - Version supported: >= 12.x
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ● ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✓ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment

Errors:   1
Warnings: 2

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.


type here
```

Comment: High Sierra? Really???

Answer (score 0):

From your error:

```
 ✖ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
   - Version found: N/A
   - Version supported: >= 12.x
```

You need to install Xcode 12 or higher and build-tools for this version.

Answer (score 0):

- FIXED
  After 2 days can't init new project (react native)
  The problem is Xcode (maybe upgrading new version - so It can't provide functions for initing new project).
- SOLUTION:
  Check if it updating: Just wait until update finish
  If not: Reinstall Xcode (remove and empty trash, reinstall)

So now, everything is resolved. Goodluck